# mdadm super slow

Tags: mdadm

had some old 2.5" SATA 500gig drives lying around and decided to turn them into a raid1 for nextcloud.

```
/dev/sdd1:
 Timing cached reads:   2476 MB in  1.99 seconds = 1241.37 MB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads: 126 MB in  3.06 seconds =  41.21 MB/sec

/dev/sde1:
 Timing cached reads:   2520 MB in  1.99 seconds = 1263.38 MB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads: 110 MB in  3.00 seconds =  36.64 MB/sec

/dev/md0:
 Timing cached reads:   2314 MB in  1.99 seconds = 1160.04 MB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads:   2 MB in 74.84 seconds =  27.37 kB/sec
```

What's going on here?

Both devices are connected via an identical sata->usb cable.

Comment: They are old. Are they mechanical hard drives? Also, they are connected via SATA > USB. That is another layer of latency and the USB is going to slow it down significantly especially if the USB version isn't recent.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like in the last test, an error occurred and took more than a minute for one of the disks to be resolved. This might be many things:

- Third test finally hit a broken sector on either or both of these disks
- Controller firmware hickups
- USB hickups due to port-powered hard drives drawing too much power if used at the same time
- USB host controller hickups due to heavy USB load (unusual that these very low data rates from the first two tests, but not rare)
- …

But what that highlights is that if all you want is 500 GB of storage, investing into a new SSD (~45€ for 500 GB attached via USB, [m.2/SATA SSDs are currently incredibly cheap](https://www.heise.de/preisvergleich/emtec-x250-ssd-power-plus-512gb-ecssd512gx250-a2168540.html?v=k&hloc=de); classical 2.5" SATA SSDs also run ~ 23€) at 23€ + 10€ for external USB-to-m.2/SATA case) is much wiser than reactivating old hard drives you have had lying around – the fact that you're using RAID 1 doesn't make your setup more stable, it just makes failure of one of these disks more survivable.

The last thing I'd do is set up nextcloud and then store its data on failing hard drives, intentionally.

Comment: The new SSDs fixed it, it must have something to do with the power draw from the mechanical drives that is gone now.